# ArcGIS Javascript Spatial Query with Lat Lng or X Y?

Tags: javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript, point, spatial-query

I am using Google Maps on the front end as all I need on this view is to show the points. When user clicks on the map in the view, it selects a point hence giving out lat and lng. I am trying to use the lat and lng to query my feature layers and to find the features containing the point but it is giving the same error again and again.

```
TypeError: undefined is not a function {stack: (...), message: "undefined is not a function"} "TypeError: undefined is not a function
at p.toJson (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:589:112)
at p.execute (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:267:406)
at A._createWrappers.p.forEach.c.(anonymous function).g.addCallbacks.d (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:723:454)
at c (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:76:221)
at b.Deferred.A.then.then [as then] (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:78:301)
at b.Deferred.addCallbacks (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:78:144)
at A._createWrappers.p.forEach.c.(anonymous function) [as execute] (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:723:382)
at http://localhost:26196/Projects/Add:4678:27
at ha (http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:32:473)
at http://js.arcgis.com/3.13/init.js:25:61"
```

The code that is throwing the error is pasted below.

```
require([
          "esri/map", "esri/tasks/query", "esri/tasks/QueryTask", "esri/SpatialReference", "esri/geometry/Point", "dojo/dom"
        ], function (Map, Query, QueryTask, SpatialReference, Point, dom) {

            var query = new Query();
            query.outSpatialReference = { wkid: 4326 };
            query.spatialRelationship = Query.SPATIAL_REL_INTERSECTS;
            query.returnGeometry = true;
            query.outFields = "*";
            var point = new Point();
            point.setX(lng);
            point.setY(lat);
            query.geometry = point;
            query.where = "1=1";
            var queryTask = new QueryTask("http://myServer/arcgis/rest/services/ApplicationServices/DataService/MapServer/6/");
            queryTask.execute(query, function(a){ debugger }, function(e){ debugger });
        });
```

I found the snippet somewhere on line, the only difference is that **query.geometry** was set as **event.Point** in the example while I am setting a point myself.

Comment: Have you tried creating the point using the code `var point = new Point(lng, lat);`

Comment: Yes, I tried it before, when it failed then I tried by initializing a new point

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the cryptic error is being thrown because query.outFields expects an [array](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/jsapi/query-amd.html#outfields)

`query.outFields = ["*"];`

Comment: Thanks a lot man! My bad I thought I was too good to copy paste the exact example for syntax. :)

Answer (score -1):

var distance, map, infobox, dataLayer, ctx, listItems, listTitle, sLat, sLon, travelDistance=0;
var BingMapsKey = "AjYUIdfUv0O7_oGQK0ohkFX_goDqb3e83CcgTXu4u54tFW1LvinADSBaoIF4eui0"

        function getDetails()
        {
    var zip = document.getElementById("tzipcode").value
    distance = document.getElementById("Ddistance").value
    var geocodeRequest = "https://dev.virtualearth.net/REST/v1/Locations?query=" + zip + "&output=json&jsonp=UpdateFields&key=" + BingMapsKey;
    CallRestService(geocodeRequest)
    getMap()
        }

        function UpdateFields(result)
        {
    if (result && result.resourceSets && result.resourceSets.length > 0 && result.resourceSets[0].resources && result.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) 
                {
        sLat = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[0] + '';
        sLon = result.resourceSets[0].resources[0].point.coordinates[1] + '';
            }
       }

       function CallRestService(request) 
       {
    var script = document.createElement("script");
    script.setAttribute("type", "text/javascript");
            script.setAttribute("src", request);
            document.body.appendChild(script);
        }

        function getMap()
        {
    map = new Microsoft.Maps.Map(document.getElementById('myMap'), {credentials: 'AjYUIdfUv0O7_oGQK0ohkFX_goDqb3e83CcgTXu4u54tFW1LvinADSBaoIF4eui0',
    zoom: 7, center: new Microsoft.Maps.Location(39.8002,-89.6487)
            });

            dataLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
map.entities.push(dataLayer);

var infoboxLayer = new Microsoft.Maps.EntityCollection();
map.entities.push(infoboxLayer);

            infobox = new Microsoft.Maps.Infobox(new Microsoft.Maps.Location(0, 0), { 
                        visible: false, 
                        offset: new Microsoft.Maps.Point(0, 20) 
                    });
            infoboxLayer.push(infobox);

            listTitle = "BrokerAgents"

            if(listTitle){
                window.parent.ExecuteOrDelayUntilScriptLoaded(loadList, 'sp.js');
            }
        }

        function loadList(){
            getListItems(listTitle);            
        }

        function getListItems(listTitle){
            ctx = new window.parent.SP.ClientContext.get_current();

var targetList = ctx.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle(listTitle);
var query = window.parent.SP.CamlQuery.createAllItemsQuery();

            listItems = targetList.getItems(query);
            ctx.load(listItems);
            ctx.executeQueryAsync(onLoadItemsSuccess, onLoadItemsFail);
        }

        function onLoadItemsFail(sender, args) {
            alert('Failed to get lists items. Error:' + args.get_message());
        }

        function onLoadItemsSuccess(sender, args) {
            var listEnumerator = listItems.getEnumerator();

            var item, pin, loc;
            while (listEnumerator.moveNext())  {
                item = listEnumerator.get_current();
                travelDistance = 0
                var itemLat = item.get_item("broker_x002d_position_x002d_lati")
                var itemLon = item.get_item("broker_x002d_position_x002d_long")
                getDistance(itemLat, itemLon)
                if(travelDistance != 0 && travelDistance  0 && result1.resourceSets[0].resources && result1.resourceSets[0].resources.length > 0) 
                {
        travelDistance = result1.resourceSets[0].resources[0].route.traveldistance + '';
            }
       }


        function displayInfobox(e) {
            if (e.targetType == 'pushpin') {
                infobox.setLocation(e.target.getLocation());
                infobox.setOptions({ 
                    visible: true, 
title: e.target.Metadata.Title, 
                    description: e.target.Metadata.Location 
                });
            }
        } 

        function getQueryStringValue(key) {
var queryString = document.URL.split("?");
            if(queryString && queryString.length > 1)
            {
var params = queryString[1].split("&");

                for (var i = 0; i

Zip Code 

Distance 

   1

mile
   5

miles
   10

miles
   15

miles
   20

miles
   25

miles

## submit {

background-color: #e56717;
  padding: .5em;
  -moz-border-radius: 5px;
  -webkit-border-radius: 5px;
  border-radius: 6px;
  color: #fff;
  font-family: 'Arial';
  font-size: 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  border: none;
}

Search